# Query is always returning 0 rows

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-native-query

I am new to Hibernate and trying to implement simple native query but I am always getting 0 rows. If the same query I am directly running in db then I can see the records.

```
    Query query = (Query) entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER_PROFILE where ROLE_ID=:roleId "
                + "and USER_EMAIL =:userEmail and USER_PWD=:password");
        query.setParameter("roleId",rolId );
        query.setParameter("userEmail", username.toLowerCase());
        query.setParameter("password", encryptedPwd);

       userInfos = query.getResultList();
```

But always userInfos list is empty. Can someone suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: wrong database?

Comment: Did you tried without the 'encryptedPwd' argument? You store the encrypted pass in the db? Enrcrypting use something like md5 and maybe is truncated ? Give more details please.

Comment: what values are contained in your attributes rolId, username & encryptedPwd for which you dont get result? plz put them in your answer as well

Comment: If you change your query to something without any parameters e.g. `"SELECT * FROM USER_PROFILE"` do you get any results?

Comment: Previously I was using Hql like Query query = (Query) entityManager
           .createQuery("from UserInfo where userEmail=:userEmail and password=:password "); and with the same argument it was working fine.

Comment: so basically the addition of the roleId parameter makes it so you get no results.

Comment: did you run your script in client directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your suggestion.
I did a mistake here and password was getting encrypted twice. :(
Fixed now.